# ¿Puedo obtener con c# los datos que aparecen al hacer click derecho -> propiedades -> detalles?

Tags: c#, archivo

Hola gente este es el primer post y me gustaria saber si puedo obtener los datos que aparecen en la imagen en especial el **Numero de version** y si puedo modificarlos.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

revise la clase file System.IO y solo he encontrado que puedo obtener el nombre del archivo y las fechas en que se ha modificado.

Comment: Segun lo que veo son propiedades de un archivo de office, y no de un archivo normal el cual podrias ver las propiedades sin problemas con System.IO

Comment: Sep lo mismo pense pero no encuentro como obtener el numero de version, ya que, es el dato que necesito aqui encontre algo parecido a lo que busco pero veo como implementarlo https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/visualstudio/vsto/how-to-read-from-and-write-to-document-properties?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gracias gente por responder pense que por ser primero post no me iban a considerar aqui el codigo funcionable si alguien mas debe hacer algo parecido:

```
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell;
using Microsoft.WindowsAPICodePack.Shell.PropertySystem;

string filePath = @"C:\temp\example.docx";
var file = ShellFile.FromFilePath(filePath);

file.Properties.System.Author.Value = new string[] { "Author #1", "Author #2" };
file.Properties.System.Title.Value = "Example Title";

var versionActual = file.Properties.System.Document.Version.Value;
file.Properties.System.Document.Version.Value = "123";
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

FUENTE: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5337683/how-to-set-extended-file-properties

Answer (score 0):

que tal?
Podes utilizar **FileVersionInfo.FileVersion**

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        FileVersionInfo myFileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(Environment.SystemDirectory + "\\Notepad.exe");

        Console.WriteLine("File: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileDescription + '\n' +
           "Version number: " + myFileVersionInfo.FileVersion);
    }
```

Para mas info: [FileVersionInfo](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.fileversioninfo.fileversion?view=netframework-4.8)

Saludos!

Comment: Gracias por responder probe y agregue la ruta. La clase me encontraba el archivo pero el FileDescription y el FileVersion me devolvian datos nulos.